# Assign elements while you loop inside a function or with append automatically

Tags: python, postgresql

I was wondering if you could help me with my problem 
I am trying to create a function that gets data frames based on SQL QUERY.

My function is:

```
    def request_data(str,conn):
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(str)
        data = pd.read_sql_query(str, conn)
        return data
```

When I try to apply my function using append method, I get what I expect as a result!

```
    Tables_to_initialize = ['sales', 'stores', 'prices']
    Tables = []
    for x in Tables_to_initialize:
    Tables.append(request_data("SELECT *  FROM {i} WHERE d_cr_bdd = 
    (SELECT MAX(d_cr_bdd) FROM {i} )  ; ".format(i = x),conn))
```

But, 
Tables is a list that contains all the sorted data frames based on my query, what i really want to do is to assign every element in my list tables to it's name, for example

```
Tables_to_initialize[0] = 'sales'
```

and i want to Tables[0] to be sales as object (data frame).

Is there any method to assign objects inside the function or with append automatically? Or any other solution?

I really appreciate your help

Best regards,

Comment: Please take the time to update your question with properly formatted python code.

Comment: Sounds like you want a dictionary instead of a list, with the key as the name perhaps?

Comment: Yes, the dictionary option might work, could you give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of objects based on given query.

```
 table = [requested_data("SELECT *  FROM {i} WHERE d_cr_bdd = (SELECT MAX(d_cr_bdd) FROM {i}".format(i)) for i in Tables_to_initialize ]
```